# Good ways to wrap around the indices for slicing in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to slice the data frame by rows or columns using `iloc`, while wrapping around the out of the bound indices. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
#Slice the rows from 2 to 4, which the dataframe only have 3 rows
print(df.iloc[2:4,:])
```

Data frame:

```
    a   b   c  
0   1   2   3  
1   4   5   6  
2   7   8   9
```

The output will be:

```
    a   b   c
2   7   8   9
```

But I want to **wrap around** the out of the bound index, which is like:

```
    a   b   c
2   7   8   9
0   1   2   3
```

In `numpy`, it is possible to use `numpy.take` to wrap around the out of the bound index for slicing. ([The numpy take link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html))

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print(array.take(range(2,4) , axis = 0, mode='wrap'))
```

The output is:

```
 [[7 8 9]
 [1 2 3]]
```

A possible solution for wrapping out in `pandas` is using the `numpy.take`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# Get the integer indices of the dataframe
row_indices = np.arange(df.shape[0])
# Wrap the slice explicitly
wrap_slice = row_indices.take(range(2,4),axis = 0, mode='wrap')
print(df.iloc[wrap_slice, :])
```

The output will be the output I want:

```
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
0  1  2  3
```

I looked into `pandas.DataFrame.take` and there is no `"wrap"` mode. ([The pandas take link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.take.html)). What is a good and easy way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try using `np.roll`:

```
df.reindex(np.roll(df.index, shift=-2)[0:2])
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
0  1  2  3
```

And, to make it a little more generic:

```
startidx = 2
endidx = 4

df.iloc[np.roll(df.index, shift=-1*startidx)[0:endidx-startidx]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use remainder division

```
import numpy as np

start_id = 2
end_id = 4
idx = np.arange(start_id, end_id, 1)%len(df)

df.iloc[idx]
#   a  b  c
#2  7  8  9
#0  1  2  3
```

---

This method actually allows you to loop around multiple times:

```
start_id = 2
end_id = 10
idx = np.arange(start_id, end_id, 1)%len(df)

df.iloc[idx]
#   a  b  c
#2  7  8  9
#0  1  2  3
#1  4  5  6
#2  7  8  9
#0  1  2  3
#1  4  5  6
#2  7  8  9
#0  1  2  3
```